# Verify an Oracle database rollback action is successful

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I verify an Oracle database rollback action is successful?  Can I use Number of rows in activity log and Number of rows in event log?

Comment: normally you just type/press rollback in the tool of your choice and it gives you some visual feedback, like a short message or a new prompt. If it didn't work you should get an error message.

Comment: thank you, but i have another question? please answer above question when we want use "backup recovery" operation.

Comment: Still don't know what you are talking about. Searching "Oracle database rollback action" just brings up this question.

Answer (score 1):

[`V$TRANSACTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_3114.htm#REFRN30291) does not contain historical information but it does contain  information about all active transactions.  In practice this is often enough to quickly and easily monitor rollbacks and estimate when they will complete.

Specifically the columns USED_UBLK and USED_UREC contain the number of UNDO blocks and records remaining.  USED_UREC is not always the same as the number of rows; sometimes the number is higher because it includes index entries and sometimes the number is lower because it groups inserts together.

During a long rollback those numbers will decrease until they hit 0.  No rows in the table imply that the transactions successfully committed or rolled back.  Below is a simple example.

```
create table table1(a number);
create index table1_idx on table1(a);
insert into table1 values(1);
insert into table1 values(1);
insert into table1 values(1);

select used_ublk, used_urec, ses_addr from v$transaction;

USED_UBLK   USED_UREC   SES_ADDR
---------   ---------   --------
1           6           000007FF1C5A8EA0
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle [LogMiner](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm), which is part of Oracle Database, enables you to query online and archived [redo log files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/onlineredo001.htm#ADMIN11302) through a SQL interface. Redo log files contain information about the history of activity on a database.

> LogMiner Benefits
>
> All changes made to user data or to the database dictionary are
>   recorded in the Oracle redo log files so that database recovery
>   operations can be performed.
>
> Because LogMiner provides a well-defined, easy-to-use, and
>   comprehensive relational interface to redo log files, it can be used
>   as a powerful data audit tool, as well as a tool for sophisticated
>   data analysis. The following list describes some key capabilities of
>   LogMiner:
>
> - Pinpointing when a logical corruption to a database, such as errors
>     made at the application level, may have begun. These might include
>     errors such as those where the wrong rows were deleted because of
>     incorrect values in a WHERE clause, rows were updated with incorrect
>     values, the wrong index was dropped, and so forth. For example, a user
>     application could mistakenly update a database to give all employees
>     100 percent salary increases rather than 10 percent increases, or a
>     database administrator (DBA) could accidently delete a critical system
>     table. It is important to know exactly when an error was made so that
>     you know when to initiate time-based or change-based recovery. This
>     enables you to restore the database to the state it was in just before
>     corruption. See Querying [V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm#i1016607) Based on Column Values
>     for details about how you can use LogMiner to accomplish this.
> - Determining what actions you would have to take to perform
>     fine-grained recovery at the transaction level. If you fully
>     understand and take into account existing dependencies, it may be
>     possible to perform a table-specific undo operation to return the
>     table to its original state. This is achieved by applying
>     table-specific reconstructed SQL statements that LogMiner provides in
>     the reverse order from which they were originally issued. See
>     [Scenario 1: Using LogMiner to Track Changes Made by a Specific
>     User](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm#i1040290) for an example.
>
>   Normally you would have to restore the table to its previous state,
>     and then apply an archived redo log file to roll it forward.
> - Performance tuning and capacity planning through trend analysis. You
>     can determine which tables get the most updates and inserts. That
>     information provides a historical perspective on disk access
>     statistics, which can be used for tuning purposes. See [Scenario 2:
>     Using LogMiner to Calculate Table Access Statistics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm#i1028674) for an
>     example.
> - Performing postauditing. LogMiner can be used to track any data
>     manipulation language (DML) and data definition language (DDL)
>     statements executed on the database, the order in which they were
>     executed, and who executed them. (However, to use LogMiner for such a
>     purpose, you need to have an idea when the event occurred so that you
>     can specify the appropriate logs for analysis; otherwise you might
>     have to mine a large number of redo log files, which can take a long
>     time. Consider using LogMiner as a complementary activity to auditing
>     database use. See the Oracle [Database Administrator's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/toc.htm) for
>     information about database auditing.)

Enjoy.